# Using real time data to avoid polluted areas

Tags: openstreetmap, osrm

I am currently working on a website where one can plan a route while avoiding polluted areas.

I use OSRM via Docker.

I use historical sensor data and weather forecasts to make a pollution forecast.
The website prompts you to define a starting point and a destination, as well as a date and timeframe and then creates the forecast for the area.

Every single request for a route would have different data, consisting of pollution level and coordinates.

My question is, how do I use my data to weight the routing profile? Or is that even possible?

It would be great, if someone could send me some sources on this issue or even explain to me how to do it.

I did read some papers on using elevation data, but the elevation doesn't change, so I am unsure on how to apply the things mentioned there.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: this is not the right place to discuss scientific computing. please take the [tour] to make yourself familiar with StackOverflow and its scope. Your post is way to broad. also I don't see how Lua is relevant here.

Comment: @Piglet OSRM routing profiles are written in lua. But I will change the question.